# How to generate vector field of $y'+2y=x^2 e^{-2x}$

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm trying to generate the vector field of $y'+2y=x^2 e^{-2x}$ using `VectorPlot`. How should I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `VectorPlot[{x',y'},...]`

```
VectorPlot[{1, x^2 Exp[-2 x] - 2 y }, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Since the equation is only of two variables, the resulting slope field should only be 2D

Comment: That makes it easier, thanks!

Comment: That is what I got, but apparently it is supposed to look like this https://imgur.com/BeucR0b, which looks similar, but flipped over the x-axis.

Comment: Looks different , probably wrong:  For `y<0` it must follow `y'[x]>0`!

Comment: The command of Maple `DETools:-dfieldplot` produces a similar plot.